# Why smart contract call() is cheaper than sendTransaction when send ether to a wallet holding ether

Tags: gas, send

```
// Solidity 
function sender(address payable _to, uint _value) private {
    (bool success,) =  _to.call{value: _value}("");
    require(success,"Fail Send By Call"); }

// ethers 
await Wallet.sendTransaction({
    to:to,
    value:value })
```

That is the code for two different ways to send ether. use solidity call() and send a transaction directly.

The recipient(to) holds the ether in a wallet(non-zero address).

In this situation, the gas cost for sending ether in both ways is shown below.

```
[Solidity call()] execution cost  10194 gas
[Ethers sendTransaction] execution cost  21000 gas
```

I was wondering why the solidity call() method is cheaper on gas. Have any ideas?

Comment: Can you share details about how you calculated the execution costs?